# How to convert multipolygons to a single polygon

Tags: polygon, c#, sql-server, dotspatial

I have converted a set of gps points to polygon and then using .makevalid() I saved them in sql server.But It converted them to multypolygons.Is there any way to fix this problem and convert them to polygon?I know that this gps points are boundries of properties so they can not be multi polygons or polygons with holes and things like that..
I use dotspatial liberary too,So I face a problem casting a multypolygon as a polygon
here is a polygon

```
POLYGON ((552640.2093302480000000 3496912.3549182300000000, 552641.2995573730000000 3496912.1746388800000000, 552663.6457929820000000 3496900.5448129600000000, 552680.9225538470000000 3496888.2575319900000000, 552699.7662645300000000 3496878.9976676900000000, 552715.9366894700000000 3496866.9463772600000000, 552728.4397688450000000 3496858.3882891300000000, 552738.1900606220000000 3496854.8517145100000000, 552753.8502507310000000 3496871.2177283400000000, 552767.1086633470000000 3496887.6737521700000000, 552779.3744439780000000 3496903.8738870700000000, 552791.1525580790000000 3496919.0217370900000000, 552805.2092227070000000 3496937.9624503900000000, 552819.4891694100000000 3496955.2041558800000000, 552829.9551720750000000 3496968.8031193700000000, 552836.5873822790000000 3496979.5396579400000000, 552823.3613915470000000 3496998.9081548800000000, 552807.1748402530000000 3497026.6323927000000000, 552786.3026356470000000 3497048.6098226500000000, 552778.6229185360000000 3497054.6560504000000000, 552776.8941149010000000 3497053.7646478500000000, 552762.2632922050000000 3497032.0524526600000000, 552760.1282207710000000 3497029.7468180900000000, 552749.1837919520000000 3497032.0416529400000000, 552734.0416126170000000 3497038.9418586400000000, 552725.6108379730000000 3497044.1481667400000000, 552709.0982113180000000 3497051.6174468700000000, 552693.1179804780000000 3497057.5936833300000000, 552681.8288149650000000 3497063.5844871000000000, 552678.9697371590000000 3497064.4990190400000000, 552673.4647355370000000 3497066.6264652900000000, 552663.2239809290000000 3497072.8455930800000000, 552651.9921630460000000 3497078.5115463200000000, 552645.6676763500000000 3497080.7463409800000000, 552642.3887847530000000 3497082.9129709600000000, 552627.0791537030000000 3497088.3724475700000000, 552615.7672507680000000 3497094.1588052100000000, 552602.0330731500000000 3497100.9641501400000000, 552597.9744087780000000 3497103.2476326900000000, 552583.3077652720000000 3497107.3539978200000000, 552579.1609549260000000 3497108.2062851200000000, 552576.9078770020000000 3497105.6492462500000000, 552576.2655392210000000 3497092.7692563500000000, 552574.3365368260000000 3497078.0432178800000000, 552573.5704421670000000 3497059.7740750100000000, 552573.5911767260000000 3497046.2749770700000000, 552572.8475194170000000 3497029.8547736200000000, 552573.2237512700000000 3497013.6725040800000000, 552573.1566385620000000 3497000.2472915100000000, 552573.0090598000000000 3496991.7177977700000000, 552572.7189856930000000 3496987.7678451800000000, 552572.6065646680000000 3496967.5974413800000000, 552573.1036995650000000 3496952.6607278600000000, 552573.2644266720000000 3496950.7569763400000000, 552586.4785491990000000 3496941.4869583900000000, 552601.1029587970000000 3496934.7790130200000000, 552612.7093213180000000 3496927.4054392600000000, 552618.8169730790000000 3496924.0453646500000000, 552634.2099541870000000 3496916.3101133300000000, 552648.0247079520000000 3496909.3472799000000000, 552640.2093302480000000 3496912.3549182300000000))"
```

and this is the result after makeValid()

```
{MULTIPOLYGON (((552643.0639850400000000 3496911.2563468700000000, 552641.2995605470000000 3496912.1746215800000000, 552640.2093505860000000 3496912.3549194300000000, 552643.0639850400000000 3496911.2563468700000000)), ((552738.1900634770000000 3496854.8516845700000000, 552753.8502197270000000 3496871.2177124000000000, 552767.1086425780000000 3496887.6737670900000000, 552779.3743896480000000 3496903.8739013700000000, 552791.1525878910000000 3496919.0217285200000000, 552805.2092285160000000 3496937.9624633800000000, 552819.4891357420000000 3496955.2041626000000000, 552829.9552001950000000 3496968.8031005900000000, 552836.5874023440000000 3496979.5396728500000000, 552823.3614501950000000 3496998.9081420900000000, 552807.1748046880000000 3497026.6323852500000000, 552786.3026123050000000 3497048.6098022500000000, 552778.6229248050000000 3497054.6560668900000000, 552776.8941650390000000 3497053.7646484400000000, 552762.2633056640000000 3497032.0524292000000000, 552760.1281738280000000 3497029.7468261700000000, 552749.1838378910000000 3497032.0416259800000000, 552734.0416259770000000 3497038.9418335000000000, 552725.6108398440000000 3497044.1481933600000000, 552709.0982666020000000 3497051.6174316400000000, 552693.1179199220000000 3497057.5936889600000000, 552681.8288574220000000 3497063.5844726600000000, 552678.9697265630000000 3497064.4990234400000000, 552673.4647216800000000 3497066.6264648400000000, 552663.2239990230000000 3497072.8455810500000000, 552651.9921875000000000 3497078.5115356400000000, 552645.6677246090000000 3497080.7463378900000000, 552642.3887939450000000 3497082.9129638700000000, 552627.0791015630000000 3497088.3724365200000000, 552615.7672119140000000 3497094.1588134800000000, 552602.0330810550000000 3497100.9641723600000000, 552597.9743652340000000 3497103.2476196300000000, 552583.3077392580000000 3497107.3540039100000000, 552579.1610107420000000 3497108.2062988300000000, 552576.9078369140000000 3497105.6492309600000000, 552576.2655029300000000 3497092.7692260700000000, 552574.3365478520000000 3497078.0432128900000000, 552573.5704345700000000 3497059.7740478500000000, 552573.5911865230000000 3497046.2749633800000000, 552572.8475341800000000 3497029.8547973600000000, 552573.2237548830000000 3497013.6724853500000000, 552573.1566162110000000 3497000.2473144500000000, 552573.0090332030000000 3496991.7177734400000000, 552572.7189941410000000 3496987.7678222700000000, 552572.6065673830000000 3496967.5974121100000000, 552573.1037597660000000 3496952.6607055700000000, 552573.2644042970000000 3496950.7569580100000000, 552586.4785156250000000 3496941.4869384800000000, 552601.1029052730000000 3496934.7789917000000000, 552612.7093505860000000 3496927.4054565400000000, 552618.8170166020000000 3496924.0453491200000000, 552634.2099609380000000 3496916.3101196300000000, 552648.0246582030000000 3496909.3472900400000000, 552643.0639850400000000 3496911.2563468700000000, 552663.6457519530000000 3496900.5447998000000000, 552680.9226074220000000 3496888.2575073200000000, 552699.7662353520000000 3496878.9976806600000000, 552715.9366455080000000 3496866.9463501000000000, 552728.4398193360000000 3496858.3883056600000000, 552738.1900634770000000 3496854.8516845700000000)))}
```

How can I pervent this happening?

Comment: Are you sure that they are simple polygons? They can be converted into multipolygons because of self-intersections. Check how they look as WKT.

Comment: @user30184 Yes they might have some intersections..How can I pervent such of this problems?I simply want to have its geometry as a polygon not multypolygon

Comment: This has been addressed in your previous questions on this same problem. Polygons are composed of an *ordered* collection of vertices. You can't put them in random order and obtain the geometry you want, and a "make valid" request won't necessarily generate the figure you want either. Since you seem to know what you want, and existing algorithms like convex hull don't seem to meet your needs, it looks like you're going to have to implement your own.

Comment: @vince So my problem is make points in order?How can I do this?Is there any way to find order of points in a gps file?

Comment: @Majid It appears that you a getting backtracks in your GPS points.  These will happen.  Based on the sample provided, one to deal with these would be to step through the points and determine the angle between the the current direction and the next.  If is is very small (<= 3 degrees?) through that point away and check the next.  Another imperfect option option is too step through the resulting multipolygon and only keep the largest polygon.

Comment: @MickyT Thanks for your help.The secund method is exactly what I have done,I am afraid that it cause problems in features..what do you think?

Comment: @Majid Again based on you sample.  You have 64 polygons.  1 with a large area, 1 with a tiny area and 62 with NULL areas.  Removing the small polygons should prove to be a problem, but you may still end up with back tracks that don't self intersect.  Think of the letter z or a lightning bolt.

Comment: @MickyT Are you sure I have 64 polygons?I only thought I have 2 that are seprated by (),I did not get what you mean of "letter z or a lightning bolt" ,Sorry for my bad English

Comment: @Majid sorry my bad, messed up my query. By the z i meant that the boundary will go along, backtrack on itself then carry on without self intersecting.  This would form a shape like a flattened z.